Iteration in web-scraping of google scholar
I am seeking to use R for web-scraping of google scholar, for instances where someone does not have a public profile.
One challenge is that there's a limit of 10 results at a time -- so, for someone with a lot of publications, multiple lines of code are required.  I'd like to iterate where possible.
Here's the 'manual' version:
packages <- c("rvest", "xml2", "curl", "data.table")
lapply(packages, library, character.only = T)

#set up searches, with a "start" counter for the successive pages of results:
url_name0 <- 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=0&q=author:"pi+campbell"&as_ylo=1998'
url_name1 <- 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&q=author:"pi+campbell"&as_ylo=1998'
url_name2 <- 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=20&q=author:"pi+campbell"&as_ylo=1998'
url_name3 <- 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=30&q=author:"pi+campbell"&as_ylo=1998'

#scrape
wp0 <- xml2::read_html(url_name0)
wp1 <- xml2::read_html(url_name1)
wp2 <- xml2::read_html(url_name2)
wp3 <- xml2::read_html(url_name3)

# Extract raw data (titles)
titles0 <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(wp0, '.gs_rt'))
titles1 <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(wp1, '.gs_rt'))
titles2 <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(wp2, '.gs_rt'))
titles3 <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(wp3, '.gs_rt'))


Now, for the latter section, it should be possible to iterate.  I've tried a for-loop:
counter <- 0:3

titles <- vector("list", length(counter))

for (i in seq_along(counter)) {
    titles[[i]] <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(wp[[i]], '.gs_rt'))
}

But this yields an error:

Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") :
no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "NULL"

(At an earlier stage I was getting a different error: )

Error in html_elements(...) : object 'wp' not found

There are subsequent operations that have a similar structure -- so if I can figure out iteration for this one, I should be able to write some more efficient code...

lapply(paste0('http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=', seq(0, 30, 10), '&q=author:"pi+campbell"&as_ylo=1998'),             \(i) xml2::read_html(i) |> rvest::html_nodes(".gs_rt") |> rvest::html_text())?

How should the output look like? Instead of paste0 can be replaced by file.path.

For what it's worth, I think scraping Google Scholar probably violates the terms of service ...

@Friede: your suggestion did work (thanks!) -- but it no longer does.  It appears that the source code for Google Scholar results has been altered in a way that means extracting with a call to ".gs_rt" no longer extracts the titles...

Hmm, never mind -- I think I was getting blocked by a "challenge" ("Prove you're not a robot") -- now expired...

You are currently storing html_documents from read_html() in individual objects (wp0 , wp1 .. ), but in your loop you attempt to access wp list that you have not set up / filled yet.
Perhaps something bit less manual, e.g. navigating through pages with rvest::session() :
library(rvest)

s <- session('http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=0&q=author:"pi+campbell"&as_ylo=1998') 

# Extract aprox. number of results (including citations) 
about_n_results <- 
  html_elements(s, "#gs_ab_md .gs_ab_mdw") |> 
  html_text() |> 
  stringr::str_extract("(?<=About )\\d+") |> 
  as.integer()

# Storage list
titles <- vector(mode = "list", length = ceiling(about_n_results / 10))

# Extract titles, store in a list, try to follow Next link;
# repeat while there is a Next link, 
# break when number of returned titles is < 10 (presumably only citations will follow)
while (!is.null(s)) {
  current_page_n <- 
    html_elements(s, "span.gs_ico_nav_current ~ b") |> 
    html_text(trim = TRUE) |> 
    as.integer()
  
  titles[[current_page_n]] <- html_elements(s, '.gs_rt a') |> html_text(trim = TRUE)
  if (length(titles[[current_page_n]]) < 10) break
  
  # Follow Next link, return NULL when there isn't one
  s <- 
    tryCatch(
      error = function(cnd) NULL,
      session_follow_link(s, xpath = "//b[text() = 'Next']/../../a")
    )
}
#> Navigating to
#> </scholar?start=10&q=author:%22pi+campbell%22&hl=en&oe=ASCII&as_sdt=0,5&as_ylo=1998>.
#> Navigating to
#> </scholar?start=20&q=author:%22pi+campbell%22&hl=en&oe=ASCII&as_sdt=0,5&as_ylo=1998>.
#> Navigating to
#> </scholar?start=30&q=author:%22pi+campbell%22&hl=en&oe=ASCII&as_sdt=0,5&as_ylo=1998>.

unlist(titles)
#>  [1] "'Black Lives Matter:'sport, race and ethnicity in challenging times"                                                                                                 
#>  [2] "'Pray (ing) the person marking your work isn't racist': racialised inequities in HE assessment practice"                                                             
#>  [3] "'He is like a Gazelle (when he runs)'(re) constructing race and nation in match-day commentary at the men's 2018 FIFA World Cup"                                     
#>  [4] "Sport, race and ethnicity in the wake of black lives matter: Introduction to the special issue"                                                                      
#>  [5] "A ('black') historian using sociology to write a history of 'black'sport: A critical reflection"                                                                     
#>  [6] "Education, Retirement and Career Transitions for'Black'Ex-Professional Footballers: From Being Idolised to Stacking Shelves"                                         
#>  [7] "Black British Students' Experiences of Assessment"                                                                                                                   
#>  [8] "'That black boy's different class!': a historical sociology of the black middle-classes, boundary-work and local football in the British East-Midlands c. 1970− 2010"
#>  [9] "White British Students' Experiences of Assessment"                                                                                                                   
#> [10] "'Race', politics and local football–continuity and change in the life of a British African-Caribbean local football club"                                            
#> [11] "THE EFFECTS OF RACIALLY INCLUSIVE ASSESSMENT ON THE RACE AWARD GAP AND ON STUDENTS'LIVED EXPERIENCES OF ASSESSMENT"                                                  
#> [12] "Cavaliers Made Us 'United': Local Football, Identity Politics and Second-generation African-Caribbean Youth in the East Midlands c.1970–9"                           
#> [13] "Electrolytes and pH changes in pre-eclamptic rats"                                                                                                                   
#> [14] "Racially Inclusive Assessment and Academic Teaching Staff"                                                                                                           
#> [15] "Race and Assessment in Higher Education: From Conceptualising Barriers to Making Measurable Change"                                                                  
#> [16] "Conceptualising Inter-and Intra-Race-Based Barriers in Assessment"                                                                                                   
#> [17] "Afterword: 12 Years a Black Race Inclusion Academic – Some Reflections on Working in a 'Postracism' Space"                                                           
#> [18] "'White digital footballers can't jump': (re)constructions of race in FIFA 20"                                                                                        
#> [19] "British South Asian Students' Experiences of Assessment"                                                                                                             
#> [20] "'Policy Shorts': Mapping and 'Tackling'Racial Inequities in HE Assessment–Summarising the Case Study"                                                                
#> [21] "Evaluating the Racially Inclusive Curricula Toolkit in HE': Empirically Measuring the Efficacy and Impact of Making Curriculum-content Racially Inclusive on the …"  
#> [22] "Discussion and Concluding Comments"                                                                                                                                  
#> [23] "Football professionals, qualifications and post-playing career preparations"                                                                                         
#> [24] "Author interview: Q and A with Dr Paul Ian Campbell, author of education, retirement and career transitions for 'black'ex-professional footballers"                  
#> [25] "“SHEA BUTTER” FROM B. PARKII STUDIES ON EXTRACTION METHODS"                                                                                                          
#> [26] "'Black Lives Matter:'sport, race and ethnicity in challenging times"                                                                                                 
#> [27] "Internet of Things (IoT) Model for the Detection of an Infectious Disease (COVID-19)"                                                                                
#> [28] "Working-class Soccer Schoolboys, Race and Education in England"                                                                                                      
#> [29] "Retirement, Training and Transitions into Non-sport Work"                                                                                                            
#> [30] "Ethnicity, Community and 'Local'Football"                                                                                                                            
#> [31] "ERGO: an integrated, user-friendly model for computing energy and greenhouse gas budgets of bioenergy systems"                                                       
#> [32] "'He is like a Gazelle (when he runs)'(re) constructing race and nation in match-day commentary at the men's 2018 FIFA World Cup."                                    
#> [33] "Intracellular Threshhold for Ionized Mg^ sup 2+^ in Rat Platelets"                                                                                                   
#> [34] "Sport, Race and Ethnicity at a time of multiple global crises."

Created on 2024-10-23 with reprex v2.1.1

Thanks for that.  I did wonder about it -- and I recall trying to do it via putting the wp objects into a list, but I obviously didn't succeed.
I have now succeeded:
`wplist <- mget(ls(pattern="^wp"))
counter <- c(1:5)
titles <- vector("list", length(counter))
for (i in seq_along(counter)) {
titles[[i]] <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(wplist[[i]], '.gs_rt'))
}
`
I have more to figure out, but this has helped me advance things.

@dbartram , this is pretty much what Friede proposed in comments, using lapply over loops is just more idiomatic approach and saves you from manually fiddling with lists.
